# Powershell: how to find the other -ExpandProperty's

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, virtual-machine, xp-mode

im tring to attach a usb device with an ID to my xp mode (virtual machine).
Here is the code i found on the internet.

```
    # Connect to Virtual PC
$vpc = new-object -comobject "VirtualPC.Application"

# Get VM name
$vmName = Read-host "Specify the name of the virtual machine that you want to use"

# List available USB devices
write-host "The following USB devices are available:"
$vpc.USBDeviceCollection | select -ExpandProperty DeviceString

# Get the USB device name
$usb = Read-host "Enter the name of the USB device that you want to connect to the virtual machine"

# Get the VM object
$vm = $vpc.findVirtualMachine($vmName)

# Get the USB object
$usbDevice = $vpc.USBDeviceCollection | ? {$_.DeviceString -eq $usb} | select -first 1

# Attach the device - this will fail if the VM is not running
$vm.AttachUSBDevice($usbDevice)
```

Now the following line gives the name of the device:

```
$vpc.USBDeviceCollection | select -ExpandProperty DeviceString
```

I want to see the ID of the Device. If you go to Device manager and select an "Unknown Device" -properties -details -Hardware IDs you'll see the id of that device and i want to get this id in Powershell so i can assagin it with the device id to my VM(xp mode)

I'm pretty new to powershell, mybe there is a way to see all the properties $vpc.USBDeviceCollection but i dont know how...

Can someone help me out?
Thx!

Comment: You can use the Get-Member command to see all the available properties for an object: $vpc.USBDeviceCollection | Get-Member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualPC.Application not have a DeviceID property.

Try read here for got it using wmi

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/02/24/displaying-usb-devices-using-wmi.aspx

Comment: the thing is, i want to attach an unknown device.
and an unknown device doesnt have a name only an ID.
I tried to give it a name in the register but it wont let me...

Comment: after this command: gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Sort Description,DeviceID | ft Description,DeviceID -auto Can you find this unknow device in the list?

Comment: Yes its first in the list with no name
Screenshot:
http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/8515/psdriver.jpg

Comment: well, now you have your DeviceID. Is not this what you want?

Comment: # Attach the device - this will fail if the VM is not running
$vm.AttachUSBDevice($usbDevice)

This only works with the name not the id, so Im stuck atm :(

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help more of this.